# Inspect Bison's $$ variable with GDB

Tags: c, gdb, yacc, bison

If I set a breakpoint in a Bison .y file, is there a way I can inspect the contents of $$ pseudo variable at that breakpoint?

Answer (score 5):

$$ is be the top of the semantic value stack. It may be a little difficult to interpret. If you really need to, the stack pointer might be called yyssp and the stack might be called yyvsa, so something like yyvsa[yyssp] might give you what you want, depending on the version of bison you're using. Look at .tab.c code that was generated.

Comment: very nice answer! But how will i be able to examine $1, $2, $3,... etc??

Answer (score 2):

Bison keeps the stacks as local variables in `yyparse()`, dynamically allocated.

Probably the easiest way to solve a temporary debugging issue is to patch `y.tab.c` so that the line `*++yyvsp = yylval` also drops a copy in a global. You may also want to hack `YYPOPSTACK()` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I redefined the type of `yylval` with `%union`:

```
%union {
  int int_val;
  double double_val;
}
```

And what I get is either `yyval.int_val` or `yyval.double_val` depending on the type of `$$`.

But just as Richard Pennington said, the best way would be to look at the generated `.tab.c` code.